# Why the CString(LPCTSTR lpsz) constructor check the high two bytes of lpsz?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

I am reading the source code of `CString` in *MFC*. I am very curious about the implementation way of constructor `CString::CString(LPCTSTR lpsz)`.

In my understanding, before copying the string indicated by `lpsz`, it only needs check whether `lpsz` is `NULL` but no need to combine with checking if `HIWORD(lpsz)` is `NULL`.

Is any *MFC* guy passing here and willing to give some explanations?

```
CString::CString(LPCTSTR lpsz)
{
    Init();
    if (lpsz != NULL && HIWORD(lpsz) == NULL)
    {
        UINT nID = LOWORD((DWORD)lpsz);
        if (!LoadString(nID))
            TRACE1("Warning: implicit LoadString(%u) failed\n", nID);
    }
    else
    {
        int nLen = SafeStrlen(lpsz);
        if (nLen != 0)
        {
            AllocBuffer(nLen);
            memcpy(m_pchData, lpsz, nLen*sizeof(TCHAR));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's not checking if lpsz is null when checking the HIWORD

Comment: How come not?  `if (lpsz != NULL && HIWORD(lpsz) == NULL)` First checks whether lpsz is NULL and if not, checks the HIWORD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It checks whether it is passed an actual pointer or an integer resource identifier from [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In the latter case it loads the string from the resources.

Comment: In the newer versions, it's a bit clearer, because the check is done in `CheckImplicitLoad` and instead of checking if HIWORD is NULL it uses the macro `IS_INTRESOURCE`

Comment: Understood. Many thanks. If lpsz is not null but lpsz's high-order word is zero, it make the low-order word into string. It just stores the string in its internal buffer. Is Windows having the hidden rule, for the address space allocated to the programmer, the high-order word means the 2^16=64KB are reserved for OS. So it is not allowed to use the low 64KB address space to store. Right? Just trying to reason why the function is designed or behaves this way.

Answer (score 1):

That is for loading a string resource.  See the [`LoadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.